# JavaScript - кликать по ссылке до появления текста, как?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В WordPress на странице редактирования поста имеется блок "Комментарии", который отображает не все комментарии, а только первые 10, и надо каждый раз кликать по кнопке "Показать ещё комментарии".

В коде ссылка выглядит так.

```
<p class="hide-if-no-js" id="show-comments"><a href="#commentstatusdiv" onclick="commentsBox.load(<?php echo $total; ?>);return false;"><?php _e( 'Show comments' ); ?></a>
```

И если комментариев много, то приходится каждый раз кликать по этой ссылке, чтобы они вcе отобразились и в конце отобразилась надпись "Больше комментариев не найдено."

```
<p class="hide-if-no-js" id="show-comments" style="display: none;">Больше комментариев не найдено.</p>
```

на `style="display: none;` обращать внимание не стоит, в CSS я добавил

```
.inside #show-comments {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Как можно за счёт одного нажатия отображать все комментарии, типа, наверное, зациклить клик, пока не появится надпись "Больше комментариев не найдено." Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Ну если комментариев 100, то лучше их сразу все не подгружать без надобности при открытии страницы редактирования поста, т.е. инициировать подгруздку всех оставшихся при клике по ссылке всё же логично. И в админке этот момент не настраивается.

Comment: Предложение хорошее :-) Знать бы что и где искать.. гугл выдал вот это https://atimmer.github.io/wordpress-jsdoc/commentsBox.html

Comment: Думаю, вся магия происходит здесь https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/js/post.js Подскажите, пожалуйста, что на что поменять.

Comment: мне кажется вы слишком глубоко копаете на данном этапе и в те глубины я  не пойду.  Смысл в том, что ```commentsBox.load``` это грубо говоря функция, которая принимает в качестве аргумента переменную ```$total``` Вот и попробуйте подставить вместо этой переменной свою цифру.  Например: вот это ```onclick="commentsBox.load(<?php echo $total; ?>);return false;"``` поменяйте на ```onclick="commentsBox.load(999);return false;"```

Comment: Я пробовал, это, пожалуй, первое, что я сделал. Однако работает некорректно, недогружает...

Comment: ```недогружает...``` Это малоинформативно. 0) Сколько недогружает? 1) Сколько всего комментариев на сайте? 2) чему равна переменная $total? 3) если писать ```onclick="commentsBox.load(999);return false;"```, то сколько подгружается комментариев при клике на кнопку?

Comment: Переменная при каждом клике меняется, видимо, это цифра для подстановки для последующего запроса через ajax идёт. Если вписать фиксированное значение, то оно не сработает должным образом. Я точнее не могу объяснить, я просто пробовал и видел, что это не работает совершенно.